# Facebook Live API with mobile and third party cameras

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, gopro, facebook-live-api

as Facebook iOS app only support device cameras for live streaming, I've started to develop an app for my GoPro camera. The problem is that I would like to switch live stream between my GoPro and iPhone cameras, but Facebook Live API states, that it shouldn't be used for mobile device cameras:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api

> <...> the API isn't intended for use with mobile phone cameras

I really don't want to use anything like Periscope or similar, because I want content to be published only to Facebook.

So.. Any advice what path should I take if I want to combine my live stream from my phone AND 3rd party cameras.. Or I just simply need to wait and to hope, that one day Facebook will implement 3rd party cameras support in Facebook App itself?

Comment: This isn't so much of a technical question as it is a policy question.  From the technical standpoint you can connect just about anything to Facebook Live... but the policy doesn't allow mobile phone cameras.  It's debatable whether or not your use case violates the policy.

Comment: can I make live ,  content being played on my mobile device(not from camera) on Facebook

Comment: I want my Running SIP call in my App to make live on Facebook.